# Recursive function not stopped as expected

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursive-datastructures

Sorry for this basic question, but it has already taken a few hours of me.
**Issue:** To right shift an array for specified steps
Here's the code:

```
static int[] ShiftRight(int[] arr, int shiftTimes)
    {
        if (shiftTimes == 0 || arr.Length == 0 || arr.Length == 1) return arr;

        var resultArray = new int[arr.Length];

        for (var i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
            resultArray[i] = arr[i - 1];

        resultArray[0] = arr[resultArray.Length - 1];

        while (shiftTimes > 1)
        {
            shiftTimes--;    
            ShiftRight(resultArray, shiftTimes);
        }            

        return resultArray;
    }
```

**Problem:**
Although the `while` expression is there to control the recursion, for some unknown reasons, after reaching the `return resultArray;` line, the program goes back to the `while` expression so that it gives a wrong result! This behavior is visible when debugging.

*The method signature must not be changed.*

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: either loop or recurse - choose one

Comment: Replace the while with if. Perhaps it might work.

Comment: @MyIsaak: just replace but still getting the wrong result - there must be else where I am making the mistake!

Comment: @pm100: absolutely correct - thanks for that but still getting wrong result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use a loop as well as recursion. Remove the while loop and just return the function itself with the updated shiftTimes variable.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = ShiftRight(new int[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}, 2);
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",arr));
    }

    static int[] ShiftRight(int[] arr, int shiftTimes)
    {
        if (shiftTimes == 0 || arr.Length == 0 || arr.Length == 1) return arr;

        var resultArray = new int[arr.Length];

        for (var i = 1; i <= arr.Length; i++)
            resultArray[i%arr.Length] = arr[i - 1];

        return ShiftRight(resultArray, --shiftTimes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the while loop at all. Recursion is all you need here - it will make sure to rerun the array is shifted until stop clause (shiftTimes==0) is reached.

Note that the variable shiftTimes, which is decreased in recursive calls is not reflected to the calling environment - the argument is passed by value, so a new copy of it is made and only the copy is decreased with each new call to `ShiftRight`.

You also do not do anything with the return value of the recursive call, you should return it.

Comment: the second paragraph was so useful for me - thanks. About the first paragraph, do you mean I should replace "while" with "if" and then it is fine? though I've done that still getting wrong result - what part I am mistaking in?

Comment: @AliAshoori You don't even need the if, because you have the stop clause when `shiftTimes == 0`, you simply return the input array - which is the same. (Adding the if is not wrong, but it is not needed).

Comment: OMG, you're right, already have the stop clause at the beginning. it's disappointing but still wrong result :-(

Comment: @AliAshoori you are also missing using the return value of the the recursive call `return ShiftRight(...)`